# How to do math calculation in angular2 template?

Tags: angular, svg

I am a beginner to angular2. And I'm confused when trying to do math calculation in angular2 template.

This works well.

```
    <g transform="rotate(30)">
          <line class="second" y1="10" y2="-38" />
          <line class="second-counterweight" y1="10" y2="2" />
    </g>
```

But this code doesn't work.

```
    <g transform="rotate({{3*10}})">
          <line class="second" y1="10" y2="-38" />
          <line class="second-counterweight" y1="10" y2="2" />
    </g>
```

The original code is from [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/e6yodTEL8fYYE9JotT3Z?p=preview), since I want to migrate it from angular 1.x to angular 2. Any helps would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try attribute syntax like:

```
[attr.transform]="'rotate(' + 3*10 + ')'"
```

**[Angular2 Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pzWSapAcJJwal1hFwOiS?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

Copy and past this:

```
<g [transform] = "'rotate(' + (3 * 10) + ')'">
  <line class = "second" y1 = "10" y2 = "-38" />
  <line class = "second-counterweight" y1 = "10" y2 = "2" />
</g>
```